# How to efficiently mutate multiple columns of a large dataframe

Tags: r, performance, function, datatable, tidyr

I would appreciate any help to efficiently apply `my function` to multiple columns of my large data frame `DT_large`.

My function works well and efficiently when I apply it with `dplyr::mutate_at()` to a small data frame `DT_small`. However, when applied to a relatively large dataset `DT_large`, available [here](https://jmp.sh/iC6WOzw), it takes `dplyr::mutate_at()` several hours to deliver the desired output.

It might be that there is some mistake in my code that is making `dplyr::mutate_at()`less efficient with my relatively large dataset. Alternatively, it might be that `dplyr::mutate_at()` is not efficient with relatively large datasets like mine.

In either case, I would appreciate any help to solve my problem, that is, a faster way to correctly apply my function to `DT_large` and deliver desired output like that I get when I apply it to `DT_small`.

**#small dataset**

```
DT_small<-structure(list(.id = 1:10, `_E1.1` = c(0.475036902, 0.680123015, 
0.896920608, 0.329908621, 0.652288128, 0.408813318, 0.486444822, 
0.429333778, 2.643293032, 0.782194143), `_E1.2` = c(79.22653114, 
0.680123015, 4.088529776, 0.232076989, 0.652288128, 0.329908621, 
0.486444822, 0.429333778, 2.643293032, 0.963554482), `_E1.3` = c(0.466755502, 
0.680123015, 0.461887024, 1.236938197, 0.652288128, 0.408813318, 
0.486444822, 0.429333778, 2.643293032, 0.95778584), `_E1.4` = c(1.608298119, 
0.680123015, 0.578464999, 0.317125521, 0.652288128, 0.408813318, 
0.486444822, 0.429333778, 2.643293032, 2.125841957), `_E1.5` = c(0.438424932, 
0.680123015, 0.896920608, 0.366118007, 0.652288128, 1.007079029, 
0.486444822, 0.429333778, 2.643293032, 0.634134022), `_E10.1` = c(0.45697607, 
0.647681721, 1.143509029, 0.435735621, 0.49400961, 0.501421816, 
0.461123723, 0.568477247, 1.756598213, 0.67895017), `_E10.2` = c(35.30312978, 
0.647681721, 2.58357783, 0.25514789, 0.49400961, 0.435735621, 
0.461123723, 0.568477247, 1.756598213, 0.776970116), `_E10.3` = c(0.79477661, 
0.647681721, 0.672430959, 0.886991224, 0.49400961, 0.501421816, 
0.461123723, 0.568477247, 1.756598213, 1.019701072), `_E10.4` = c(1.912254794, 
0.647681721, 0.840757508, 0.414669983, 0.49400961, 0.501421816, 
0.461123723, 0.568477247, 1.756598213, 1.576577576), `_E10.5` = c(0.429335115, 
0.647681721, 1.143509029, 0.336512868, 0.49400961, 0.82434125, 
0.461123723, 0.568477247, 1.756598213, 0.639407175), `_E100.1` = c(0.567579678, 
0.780423094, 1.739967261, 0.282217304, 0.784904687, 0.319146371, 
0.585056235, 0.596494912, 3.545358563, 0.899595619)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

**#large dataset**

```
1) download to your directory from https://jmp.sh/iC6WOzw
2) DT_large <- read_csv("DT_large.csv")
```

**#my function**

```
my_dataset$new_variable <- ifelse(my_dataset$old_variable >quantile(
my_dataset$old_variable,probs=0.80),quantile(
my_dataset$old_variable,probs=0.80),my_dataset$old_variable)
```

**#my function applied to my small dataset**

```
//this perfectly delivers the desired output in seconds
DT_small %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("_E")),
                 funs(ifelse(
         DT_small$.>quantile(
                 DT_small$.,probs=0.80),quantile(
                 DT_small$.,probs=0.80),DT_small$.)))
```

**#my function applied to my large dataset**

```
//this takes several hours to deliver the desired output
DT_large %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("_E")),
                 funs(ifelse(
         DT_large$.>quantile(
                 DT_large$.,probs=0.80),quantile(
                 DT_large$.,probs=0.80),DT_large$.)))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a pretty big speedup by: 1.) computing the quantile once, and 2.) applying your new more parsimonious function to the columns.

On my machine this approach is about 15x faster.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

dplyr_res <- DT_small %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("_E")),
                       funs(ifelse(
                         DT_small$.>quantile(
                           DT_small$.,probs=0.80),quantile(
                             DT_small$.,probs=0.80),DT_small$.)))

fun_col <- function(col) { 
  m <- quantile(col, .8) # compute once
  ifelse(col > m, m, col)
}

sapply_res <- sapply(DT_small[,2:ncol(DT_small)], fun_col)


dplyr_res %>% dplyr::select(-.id) == sapply_res
#>       _E1.1 _E1.2 _E1.3 _E1.4 _E1.5 _E10.1 _E10.2 _E10.3 _E10.4 _E10.5
#>  [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [6,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [7,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [8,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>  [9,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#> [10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
#>       _E100.1
#>  [1,]    TRUE
#>  [2,]    TRUE
#>  [3,]    TRUE
#>  [4,]    TRUE
#>  [5,]    TRUE
#>  [6,]    TRUE
#>  [7,]    TRUE
#>  [8,]    TRUE
#>  [9,]    TRUE
#> [10,]    TRUE



microbenchmark(dplyr_res = DT_small %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("_E")),
                                                  funs(ifelse(
                                                    DT_small$.>quantile(
                                                      DT_small$.,probs=0.50),quantile(
                                                        DT_small$.,probs=0.50),DT_small$.))),
               sapply_res = sapply(DT_small[,2:ncol(DT_small)], fun_col))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
#>   dplyr_res 12.372519 12.668833 13.577804 12.856150 13.553805 60.220232
#>  sapply_res  1.808413  1.850595  1.966174  1.874696  1.911037  3.441024
#>  neval cld
#>    100   b
#>    100  a
```

Saving on recomputing is probably doing a bunch of the work here. I didn't explicitly test to see if `sapply()` is faster than `mutate_at`.

#### Quick example of running in parallel (only worth it if many columns)

```r
parallel::mcmapply(fun_col, DT_small %>% select(-.id))
```

Depends on having the parallel package installed.

Comment: Thanks, @gfgm. My objective is not to calculate medians. Just edited the question to what I am actually doing.

Comment: ok, well if you switch to my approach and swap median with `quantile(x, .8)` its still about 7-8x faster. Will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for this, @gfgm. Waiting for the edited answer. I will then apply to the large data and report the outcome. Importantly, this `matches("_E")` is important because the actual dataset has other columns, so I need something like `matches("_E")` to automatically identify the columns to apply the function.

Comment: @Krantz done. I didn't look at how big your big data was. If it has many many columns you may want to consider applying `fun_col()` to the columns in parallel.

Comment: Great, @gfgm. I need something like `matches("_E")` (instead of  `2:ncol(DT_small)]`) to automatically identify the columns (all columns that begin with `_E`) to apply the function. Also, how could the task be parallelized by column? By the way, I have more than 100,000,000 columns in my actual dataset. Thanks for this very helpful insight.

Comment: just do `sapply(DT_small %>% select(matches("_E")), fun_col)`.

Comment: Just tested `fun_col <- function(col) { 
  m <- quantile(col, .8) # compute once
  ifelse(col > m, m, col)}
  sapply_res <- sapply(DT_large %>% select(matches("_E")), fun_col)`. You solution provides tremendous gain in performance but creates one problem by removing other variables from the dataset and keeping only those `select(matches("_E"))`. That behaviour is undesired. Specifically, I need the other variables, such as `.id`, kept unchanged after the operation. Any solution?

Comment: You need to assign the output to the variables you want to edit e.g. `DT_small[, grepl("_E", names(DT_small))] <- sapply(...)`. This will alter the values of the columns of your existing data.frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, @gfgm. Your code solved my problem. I can now get the desired output with my large dataset in second. Very helpful input!