# How to efficiently select a random sample of variables from a set of variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, random, data.table, tidyr

I would appreciate any help to randomly select a subset of `var.w_X` 
containing `5` out of `10` `var.w_X` variables from my sample data `sampleDT`, while keeping all the other variables that do not start with`var.w_`.

Below is the sample data `sampleDT` which contains, among other variables (those to be kept altogether), `X` variables starting with `var.w_` in their names (those from which to draw the random sample).

In the current example, `X=10`, so that `var.w_` includes `var.w_1` to `var.w_10`, and I want to draw a random sample of `5` out of these `10`. However, in my actual data, `X>1,000,000`and I might want to draw a sample of `7,500` `var.w_` variables out of these `X>1,000,000`.

Therefore, accounting for efficiency is paramount in any given solution since [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706239/how-to-efficiently-mutate-multiple-columns-of-a-large-dataframe) I experienced some performance issues with `mutate_at` whose cause I still don't have an explanation.

Importantly, the other variables to keep (those that do not start with `var.w_`) are not guaranteed to stay in any pre-specified order, as they might be located before and/or between and/or after the `var.w_` variables, for example. So solutions that rely on order of columns will not work.

**#sample data**

```
sampleDT<-structure(list(n = c(62L, 96L, 17L, 41L, 212L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 
73L, 73L), r = c(3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 170L, 21L, 0L, 33L, 62L, 17L
), p = c(0.0483870967741935, 0.0104166666666667, 0, 0.0487804878048781, 
0.80188679245283, 0.146853146853147, 0, 0.230769230769231, 0.849315068493151, 
0.232876712328767), var.w_8 = c(1.94254385942857, 1.18801169942857, 
3.16131123942857, 3.16131123942857, 1.13482609242857, 1.13042157942857, 
2.13042157942857, 1.13042157942857, 1.12335579942857, 1.12335579942857
), var.w_9 = c(1.942365288, 1.187833128, 3.161132668, 3.161132668, 
1.134647521, 1.130243008, 2.130243008, 1.130243008, 1.123177228, 
1.123177228), var.w_10 = c(1.94222639911111, 1.18769423911111, 
3.16099377911111, 3.16099377911111, 1.13450863211111, 1.13010411911111, 
2.13010411911111, 1.13010411911111, 1.12303833911111, 1.12303833911111
), group = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), treat = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), c1 = c(1.941115288, 
1.186583128, 1.159882668, 1.159882668, 1.133397521, 1.128993008, 
1.128993008, 1.128993008, 1.121927228, 1.121927228), var.w_6 = c(1.939115288, 1.184583128, 
3.157882668, 3.157882668, 1.131397521, 1.126993008, 2.126993008, 
1.126993008, 1.119927228, 1.119927228), var.w_7 = c(1.94278195466667, 
1.18824979466667, 3.16154933466667, 3.16154933466667, 1.13506418766667, 
1.13065967466667, 2.13065967466667, 1.13065967466667, 1.12359389466667, 
1.12359389466667), c2 = c(0.1438, 
0.237, 0.2774, 0.2774, 0.2093, 0.1206, 0.1707, 0.0699, 0.1351, 
0.1206), var.w_1 = c(1.941115288, 1.186583128, 3.159882668, 3.159882668, 
1.133397521, 1.128993008, 2.128993008, 1.128993008, 1.121927228, 
1.121927228), var.w_2 = c(1.931115288, 1.176583128, 3.149882668, 
3.149882668, 1.123397521, 1.118993008, 2.118993008, 1.118993008, 
1.111927228, 1.111927228), var.w_3 = c(1.946115288, 1.191583128, 
3.164882668, 3.164882668, 1.138397521, 1.133993008, 2.133993008, 
1.133993008, 1.126927228, 1.126927228), var.w_4 = c(1.93778195466667, 
1.18324979466667, 3.15654933466667, 3.15654933466667, 1.13006418766667, 
1.12565967466667, 2.12565967466667, 1.12565967466667, 1.11859389466667, 
1.11859389466667), var.w_5 = c(1.943615288, 1.189083128, 3.162382668, 
3.162382668, 1.135897521, 1.131493008, 2.131493008, 1.131493008, 
1.124427228, 1.124427228)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**#my attempt**

```
//based on the comment by @akrun - this does not keep the other variables as specified above

myvars <- sample(grep("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE), 5)
sampleDT_test <- sampleDT[myvars]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Try `sample(grep("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE), 5)`

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. Doing `sampleDT_test<-sample(grep("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE), 5)` gives `head(sampleDT_test)
[1] "var.w_4" "var.w_7" "var.w_6"
[4] "var.w_9" "var.w_5"`, which is not what I want as detailed in the question.

Comment: Is there a reason just doing `c(names(sampleDT)[1:7], sampleDT_test)` would not work to subset your dataset? I.e., `sampleDT[,c(names(sampleDT)[1:7], sampleDT_test)]`. If that does not work for your dataset, can you provide more detail as to why?

Comment: @Andrew, because as specified in the question itself  `In the current example, X=10, so that var.w_ includes var.w_1 to var.w_10, and I want to draw a random sample of 5 out of these 10. However, in my actual data, X>1,000,000and I might want to draw a sample of 7,500 var.w_ variables out of these X>1,000,000.`. Therefore, I need a more efficient and scalable approach and randomness is paramount.

Comment: @Krantz, I read your question. It is not clear to me how akrun's solution is not adaptable to solve your problem. Is it too slow, does it not return what you would like to see, can you provide more information about why it does not work / what more is needed in a way that is different than quoting your question?

Comment: @Andrew, because as specified in the question itself `I would appreciate any help to randomly select a subset of var.w_X containing 5 out of 10 var.w_X variables from my sample data sampleDT, while keeping all the other variables that do not start with var.w_.`. In my attempt using the solution by @akrun, I am unable to keep the other variables that do not start with `var.w_1`. Thanks.

Comment: True, but why would it not work to just keep those variable and then use akrun's solution. I.e., `myvars <- c(names(sampleDT)[1:7],
            sample(grep("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE), 5))
sampleDT[myvars]`

Comment: @Andrew, to avoid extended discussions in comments could you please kindly post your thoughts as an answer? Additionally, this `myvars <- c(names(sampleDT)[1:7], sample(grep("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE), 5)) sampleDT[myvars]` relies on the assumption of those variables that do not start with `var.w_` being the first 7 columns in the data frame, which is not the case as specified in the question itself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, had to step into a meeting for a little bit. So, I think you could adapt akrun's solution and keep the first columns for the sample dataframe. Let me know how this scales on the full dataframe. Also, thanks for clarifying further.

```
> # Subsetting the variable names not matching your pattern using grepl
> names(sampleDT)[!grepl("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT))]
[1] "n"     "r"     "p"     "group" "treat" "c1"    "c2"   
> 
> # Combine that with akrun's solution 
> myvars <- c(names(sampleDT)[!grepl("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT))],
+             sample(grep("var\\.w_", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE), 5))
> head(sampleDT[myvars])
    n   r          p group treat       c1     c2  var.w_6  var.w_1  var.w_4  var.w_3  var.w_8
1  62   3 0.04838710     1     0 1.941115 0.1438 1.939115 1.941115 1.937782 1.946115 1.942544
2  96   1 0.01041667     1     0 1.186583 0.2370 1.184583 1.186583 1.183250 1.191583 1.188012
3  17   0 0.00000000     0     0 1.159883 0.2774 3.157883 3.159883 3.156549 3.164883 3.161311
4  41   2 0.04878049     1     0 1.159883 0.2774 3.157883 3.159883 3.156549 3.164883 3.161311
5 212 170 0.80188679     0     0 1.133398 0.2093 1.131398 1.133398 1.130064 1.138398 1.134826
6 143  21 0.14685315     1     1 1.128993 0.1206 1.126993 1.128993 1.125660 1.133993 1.130422
```

> 

Comment: Great @Andrew! This works well with `sampleDT`. I will test it with my large dataset and report if I experience any performance issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help, hopefully it scales well!!

Comment: Actually, if that is too slow, you could switch out `grep` / `grepl` with `startsWith`. If you have several million columns, it may make a difference when creating myvars. You just cannot use regex with `startsWith`, so if you need regex it wont work.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. I tested your solution with my large datasets and it works perfectly. Thanks for the input!